# How would you proof that this series is convergent (no solution needed)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Analyze if the series is convergent:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n^{3}+3n^{2}+1}{2^{n}}$$

I have used ratio test and I got $\frac{1}{2}$ as result which seems pretty good, it's also smaller than $1$...

But I'm not looking for a solution here. Problem with ratio test was, it took me half of a page and too much time. I didn't even have to think how to deform while I used the ratio test, I did it really fast (anyway was slow). There aren't easier and faster ways of solving this? In the exam I only got 120 minutes and a task like that is one of many tasks there.

I can imagine there is a way which doesn't require you more than 2 lines, I have needed almost 7 lines (half DIN A4)...

Comment: $2n^3+3n^2+1\sim 2n^3$  as $n\to \infty $

Comment: $n^{\alpha}$ vs $a^n$...

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Ratio test should be the fastest way. Comparisons require justification, and you would possibly have to use induction to prove any claim.

Comment: When you have a polynomial over an exponential you can make a really bad upperbound about the polynomial like $2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1 < 2n^3 + 3n^3 + 1n^3 = 6n^3$ and then apply the ratio test. Exponentials are "infinitely more powerful" than polynomials so don't hesitate to find tremendously bad upper bounds as long as it is a polynomial and makes your life easier.

Comment: Zubzub, I need to note it like you when I do this? Or can I just do it as Behrouz Maleki did it (see below)?

Comment: @cnmesr, a question like "how much justification do I need to show" can only be answered by your prof.  To some people limits (like polynomial / exponential) are easy to see quickly, others might want more explicit justification.  It depends a lot on where you are in your studies.  Calc II (probably going to want more justification) a real analysis class, probably not so much on that particular point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\left| \frac{{{a}_{n+1}}}{{{a}_{n}}} \right|=\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{\frac{2{{(n+1)}^{3}}+3{{(n+1)}^{2}}+1}{{{2}^{n+1}}}}{\frac{2{{n}^{3}}+3{{n}^{2}}+1}{{{2}^{n}}}}=\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{\frac{2{{n}^{3}}}{{{2}^{n+1}}}}{\frac{2{{n}^{3}}}{{{2}^{n}}}}=\frac 12$$

Comment: Oh your ratio test is way shorter than mine! Is it even allowed to ignore the other things in the enumerators?

Comment: yes ,note  $2(n+1)^3+3(n+1)^2+1\sim 2n^3$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

you could use comparison test for non-negative sequences .

you have : $$0\le a_n \le \dfrac{6n \ ^ 3}{ 2 \ ^ n} $$

from here because that $lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{6\ ^{1/n} n\ ^ {3/n} }{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} $ you could finish.

Is that works for you ?

Answer (score 1):

I already knew that $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n})^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)2^{-n}$.

So $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n})^4=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{P(n)}{2^n}$ where $P(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$. It really doesn't matter which polynomial, so I would quickly say it converges (assuming its for a GRE test or something of the sort)